# When building curl from source getting .so file with wrong curl version, why?

Tags: curl, embedded-linux, libcurl

I'm cross compiling from source the latest curl version

```
curl version: 7.52.1-DEV
```

However, after make is done I'm getting library files with version 4.4.0

```
curl$ ls -la build/lib/
total 2636
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins    4096 Jan 15 19:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 jenkins jenkins    4096 Jan 15 19:47 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins  536018 Jan 15 19:47 libcurl.a
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins    1127 Jan 15 19:47 libcurl.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins      16 Jan 15 19:47 libcurl.so -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins      16 Jan 15 19:47 libcurl.so.4 -> libcurl.so.4.4.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jenkins jenkins 2143917 Jan 15 19:47 libcurl.so.4.4.0
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Jan 15 19:47 pkgconfig
```

Does anyone can explain why is it 4.4.0 when the curl version from the ./configure is 7.52.1

Is it possible to change it so it has the proper version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "4.4.0" is the [SONAME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) of the libcurl as installed on your system. It is not the same as the version number.

A lot of libcurl versions create the same SONAME version as long as libcurl remains on SONAME major version 4, it is binary compatible. The numbers are generally there to allow you to keep old applications linked to older libraries and have new applications link with newer.

So you figure out which libcurl version these files were built from, you need to run `curl_version()` or similar. Or check in the corresponding include headers if you're sure they were installed from the same source code. Optionally, you have `curl-config` or `pkg-config` present that *also* can show which curl version you have installed.

[Under the hood, the number "4.4.0" is set as "8:0:4" in [lib/Makefile.am](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/Makefile.am#L85), and is transformed/used by libtool when the .so file is generated in the build process.]

General [ABI rules and guarantees](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/abi.html) for libcurl.